# Не подключается файл .tpl в index.php на сервере

Tags: php

Ниже вставляю часть кода, в котором подключаю к index.php шаблон header.tplю Часть кода php вставляется в header.tpl вместо

```
$template = file ('header.tpl');
if(!isset($html)) { $html = "Eror 404"; $page_name=" : Eror 404"; }
if(!isset($page_name)) { $page_name=" : Error Name Page"; }

foreach ($template as $temp) {
$temp = ereg_replace("<!--text-->", "$html", $temp);
echo "$temp";
}
```

На OSPanel все работает, устанавливаю на сервер, не работает. Пробовала указать путь $template = file ('../header.tpl'); все равно не работает.
Подскажите, как переписать код, чтоб и на сервере подключался файл?

Comment: `file ('../header.tpl')` если вы указывали такой путь то могу сказать что вы вышли на одну директорию вверх, правильней наверное будет `file(dirname(__DIR__)."/header.tpl");` если у вас header.tpl в главном каталоге лежит

Comment: включить отображение ошибок, и увидеть, что `ereg_replace` вообще удален как рудимент из пхп7, который у вас на сервере? далее почитать про шаблонизаторы в пхп, и выбрать нечто вразумительное и современное,  а не пихать регулярные выражения туда, где они не к месту.